# local.ERROR: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-9

```
 public function sku_combination(Request $request)
    {
        $options = array();
        if ($request->has('colors_active') && $request->has('colors') && count($request->colors) > 0) {
            $colors_active = 1;
            array_push($options, $request->colors);
        } else {
            $colors_active = 0;
        }

        $unit_price = $request->unit_price;
        $product_name = $request->name;

        if ($request->has('choice_no')) {
            foreach ($request->choice_no as $key => $no) {
                $name = 'choice_options_' . $no;
                $data = array();
                // foreach (json_decode($request[$name][0]) as $key => $item) {
                foreach ($request[$name] as $key =>$item) {
                    // array_push($data, $item->value);
                    array_push($data, $item);
                }
                array_push($options, $data);
            }
        }

        $combinations = Combinations::makeCombinations($options);
        return view('backend.product.products.sku_combinations', compact('combinations', 'unit_price', 'colors_active', 'product_name'));
    }
```

The array showing ,given null how to fix this.in this the foreach argument must be of type array|object but null given

The blade file for it is

```
<tbody>
@foreach($attributes as $key => $attribute)
 <tr>
   <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
   <td>{{$attribute->getTranslation('name')}}</td>
   <td>
    @foreach($attribute->attribute_values as $key => $value)
    <span class="badge badge-inline badge-md bg-soft-dark">{{ $value->value }}</span>
   @endforeach
   </td>
   <td class="text-right">
   @can('view_product_attribute_values')
  <a class="btn btn-soft-info btn-icon btn-circle btn-sm" href="{{route('attributes.show', $attribute->id)}}" title="{{ translate('Attribute values') }}">
 <i class="las la-cog"></i>
 </a>
@endcan
@can('edit_product_attribute')
<a class="btn btn-soft-primary btn-icon btn-circle btn-sm" href="{{route('attributes.edit', ['id'=>$attribute->id, 'lang'=>env('DEFAULT_LANGUAGE')] )}}" title="{{ translate('Edit') }}">
<i class="las la-edit"></i>
</a>
@endcan
 @can('delete_product_attribute')
<a href="#" class="btn btn-soft-danger btn-icon btn-circle btn-sm confirm-delete" data-href="{{route('attributes.destroy', $attribute->id)}}" title="{{ translate('Delete') }}">
<i class="las la-trash"></i>
 </a>
@endcan
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

is this  the details what you wanted.in this the name values given the error showing foreach argument must be of type array|object but given null

Comment: This is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74798949/foreach-argument-must-be-of-type-arrayobject-null-given-in-laravel where you were asked to provide more information.

Comment: more information about the blade file?

Comment: You have 2 `foreach` loops, we don't know which is causing the problem.  You would need to look at the values each one uses and see what it contains (`$request->choice_no` and possibly `$request[$name]`).   Without knowing what that data contains, it's difficult to know how to fix your problem.

Comment: the error showing in the second loop

Comment: So you need to look at the value of `$request[$name]`, probably `var_dump($request);` before the `foreach` will show you what data you have.

Comment: i just updated the question can u look

Comment: when iam adding attributes the error showing

Comment: The details you have added have nothing to do with what I asked for - what does `var_dump($request);` show before the loop.

Comment: Does ` $request` has a name attribute? `foreach ($request[$name] as $key =>$item) {`

Comment: I don't think you need to show your blade code yet. Laravel has a debug function called `dd()`, try to use it many, many times. It will show the contents of arrays, etc. Similar to var_dump, but nicer layout.

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $attribute = new Attribute;
        $attribute->name = $request->name;
        $attribute->save();

        $attribute_translation = AttributeTranslation::firstOrNew(['lang' => env('DEFAULT_LANGUAGE'), 'attribute_id' => $attribute->id]);
        $attribute_translation->name = $request->name;
        $attribute_translation->save();

        flash(translate('Attribute has been inserted successfully'))->success();
        return redirect()->route('attributes.index');
    }